# how to make streamers

Tags: mesh

I have a image attached. I want to make that streamers. Im not getting how to coil that shape round and round from top to bottom with large and top and smaller at bottom[image].

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a floor full of serpentines - streamers?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63195/how-to-create-a-floor-full-of-serpentines-streamers)

Comment: Check steps 2 - 4 of the accepted answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63662/30849. Karolina explains how to adjust the shape of a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in primitive for 'growing spirals' in the extra curves addon shipped by default with Blender

Just activate the addon *Add curve extra objects* and add it through the menu adjusting settings as desired.
You can then add another flat curve as bevel object for a ribbon effect

[image: Streamer bezier curve]

Comment: Im using blender 2.77a and i have activated the add curve in that im getting only the spiral u having sub menu of archemedian, spheric, etc. Is there any other addon or how to get that addon ur using. That feature or options not showing in my add curve spirals. An image attach above u know that my spiral settings are different from yours.

Comment: Upgrade to 2.78

Comment: i have unistall and download the new version and then install or is there any option to update. And if i do manually will my addon will be save or i have to install again all

Comment: Don't use formal installs, use the zipped standalone versions as a portable application. Its a lot safer and less error prone. Also Blender has no automatic updater anyway, so you will always have to do a full download and install