# How to setup cloth animation to make ribbons?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I want to make long confetti ribbons, lying on the surface (floor).
I wanted to achieve the volume of scrambled ribbons on the floor **if possible**. If not I wish it just save the form (width).

[image]

But by some reasons the simulation gives me the slim terrible threads.
The ribbons looks good in small amount, but not the wall.

The result of simulation. The little wind and turbulence used.

[image]

The mesh is one object with lose parts. I tried with and without randomized mesh. Also I tried to subdivide mesh one time, but the endings still loose the width.

[image]

The cloth settings

[image]

The surface settings

[image]

**How to save the ribbons form but scramble it on the floor like in example?**

Comment: Use Edge Crease on all outer edges.

Comment: Might find some ideas in the answers here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63195/how-to-create-a-floor-full-of-serpentines-streamers/63208#63208

Comment: @LukeD thanks, but the same problem: https://goo.gl/HCytjp , https://goo.gl/nH9J3k

Comment: @IlyaKanatov The links you provided won't work, add them as edit. Also move Subsurf Modifier above Cloth.

Comment: @LukeD oh, sorry about that!
https://monosnap.com/file/z5JFJVDo9ud2TjN8NWCp390RtV1Cd8# , https://monosnap.com/file/iYivCFbttbGDt7vwKNfGOYDRrUAc19

Comment: @LukeD as I said, I tried to subdivide mesh one time, but the endings still loose the width.

Comment: But did you move Subsurf Modifier to the top in modifier stack? It should be above Cloth modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LukeD, @Patdog thanks guys!

This combination are works:

- Avoid close gaps between mesh if "self collision" enabled. I placed my ribbons in checker order.
- Use one subdivision for simple meshes. By placing subdiv modifier first or subdivision manually.
- Use Harmonic force

[image]